# Evaluate $\iint_{[0,1]^2}\frac{dxdy}{(1+x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

> Evaluate: $$I=\iint_{[0,1]^2}\frac{dxdy}{(1+x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}.$$

*Attempt*. Working on substitution $x=\sqrt{1+y^2}\,\sinh u$ we get
$$I=\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{(1+y^2)\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}}\Bigg|_{0}^{1}\,dy=\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{dy}{(1+y^2)\sqrt{2+y^2}}$$ and then working on $y=\sqrt{2}\,\tan u$ we get:
$$I=\arctan\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{y^2+2}}\right)\bigg|_{0}^{1}=\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)=\frac{\pi}{6}.$$

On the other hand, polar coordinates give:

$$I=\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/4}\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{1}{\cos \phi}}\frac{r}{(1+r^2)^{3/2}}dr d\phi+\int\limits_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sin \phi}}\frac{r}{(1+r^2)^{3/2}}dr d\phi$$
which gets us to:
$$I=\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/4}\left(1-\frac{\cos\phi}{\sqrt{1+\cos^2\phi}}\right)d\phi+\int\limits_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\left(1-\frac{\sin\phi}{\sqrt{1+\sin^2\phi}}\right)d\phi$$
and the computations seem difficult to handle.

Is there an easier way to approach the calculation of this integral?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, note that the two integrals in the last line are equal. Just substitute $\phi=\frac{\pi}{2}-\varphi$ and see. Therefore

$$I=2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\left(1-\frac{\cos\phi}{\sqrt{2-\sin^{2}\phi}}\right){\rm d\phi}=\left[\begin{matrix}\sin\phi=\sqrt{2}\sin\theta\\\cos\phi{\rm d}\phi=\sqrt{2}\cos\theta{\rm d}\theta\end{matrix}\right]=$$

$$=\frac{\pi}{2}-2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}}\frac{\cos\theta}{\sqrt{1-\sin^{2}\theta}}{\rm d}\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{3}=\frac{\pi}{6}$$

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution that takes the issue right at its beginning. Your idea to turn to polar coordinates and divide the integration domain into two triangles $OAB$ and $OBC$ (with $A(1,0),B(1,1)$ and $C(0,1)$) is good. You should do it at once.  One gets :

$$I=\iint_{[0,1]^2}\frac{dxdy}{(1+x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}=I_1+I_2$$

where

$$I_1=\int_{\theta=0}^{\theta=\pi/4}\int_{r=0}^{r=1/\cos{\theta}}\frac{1}{(1+r^2)^{3/2}}\color{red}{r}drd\theta=$$

and $I_2$ is in fact equal to $I_1$ for an evident symmetry reason. (please note that $\color{red}{r}$ is the jacobian of this change of variables). Thus :

$$I=2I_1=2\int_{\theta=0}^{\theta=\pi/4}[-\frac{1}{(1+r^2)^{1/2}}]_{r=0}^{r=1/\cos(\theta)} d\theta$$

giving :

$$I=2\int_{\theta=0}^{\theta=\pi/4}(1-\frac{1}{(1+(1/\cos(\theta)^2)^{1/2}})d\theta=2\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\int_{\theta=0}^{\theta=\pi/4}\frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sqrt{1+\cos(\theta)^2}}d\theta\right)$$

where the remaining integral, transformed into :

$$\int_{\theta=0}^{\theta=\pi/4}\frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sqrt{2 -\sin(\theta)^2}}d\theta$$

is readily integrated using antiderivative :

$$\sin^{-1}\left(\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin(\theta)\right)$$

giving finally :

$$I=2(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\pi}{6})=\frac{\pi}{6}$$

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+-sqrt(2-sin%5E2(x))&t=crmtb01

Comment: @eranreches Thanks very much, I have fixed my error.

Comment: @eranreches... and erased my erroneous commentary about your change of variable....

Comment: +1 Great! Now it is basically the same as the change of variable I made. Your antiderivative is essentially my $\theta$.